# Is there a way to keep the file extension of ejs file as .html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I am developing an expressjs app using ejs templating  engine. But i want to use keep the extension of ejs file like  home.html instead of using home.ejs. The reason for this i am using visual studio for development and visual studio doesn't support ejs file. so code hinting formatting and highlighting doesn't work.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


app.set("view engine", "ejs");//setting ejs view engine
app.set("views", "./views");

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
})
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of configuring Visual Studio so that it knows `.ejs` files should be treated as `.html`? It seems like this is asking the wrong question.

Comment: i think @loganfsmyth is right, you need to configure your VS to acknowledge .ejs file so it's treated that file as a html.

Answer (score 2):

I'm manage to solve this issue , my code similar to @homam answer, but I'll write the code more completely

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const engine = require('ejs');
const app = express();

app.engine('html', engine.__express);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

//this route will open profil.html in folder ./views
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  //render file profil.html
  res.render('profil', {
    name: 'Danang Ponorogo'
  });
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server is running at port 3001');
});
```

Hope it help. Thanks.

Comment: Embedded JavaScript templating [https://ejs.co](https://ejs.co)

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);` of ejs npm module:

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: do you know if we can do the same with js files, since `app.engine('.js', require('ejs').__express);` doesn't seem to work?
`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me when I use a small ejs with my index.html file like this:
`<% if (!user) { %>
<p>hello</p>
<% } %>`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with using Visual Studio for working with ejs files. The best way, I believe is to configure Visual Studio to interpret ejs file as html by going to menu - TOOLS-->Options-->Text Editor-->FileExtension and add ejs file extension against HTML Editor.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipab3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [app.engine(ext, callback)](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.engine)

Set the following up with your view engine and views settings near the top:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Then when you call `res.render` the only difference is that you need to specify the extension:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render("home.html", { myString: "I'm a normal string!" });  
});
```

You'll find that `<%=myString%>` is handled as you would expect it to in an .ejs file.